# Append variable to a group of links on hover

Tags: jquery

Trying to append a variable to a group of links within a div on hover, and remove on mouseout. I'm having multiple issues with this.

```
$('a').hover(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".box li a").attr("href", link + '?color=' + somerandomcolor);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="box1">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="link1.html">Black</a></li>
      <li><a href="link2.html">Red</a></li>
      <li><a href="link3.html">Blue</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="box2">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="link1.html">Green</a></li>
     <li><a href="link2.html">Red</a></li>
     <li><a href="link3.html">Blue</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Noted issues. This adds the variable as it should, and continues adding it each time I hover over a link so I end up with link.html?color=black?color=red. Another problem is that if I have another div with the box class that has links, it changes those links as well. I suppose I'm looking for a solution that would pretty much reset each mouseout. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is appending each time is that you have not defined any function to handle the mouseout case.

Here is a simple approach using mouseover() and mouseout(),

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").mouseover(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", link + '?color=');    
});
$("a").mouseout(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    var n = link.indexOf("?color=");
    link = link.substring(0,n);
    $(this).attr("href", link);    
});
```

});

**UPDATE:** I have added the `this` keyword which only alters a single link rather than all the `a` elements

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/v9bm72kr/2/)

Comment: This properly removes the duplicates, yet I still have the issue when I roll over a different link, it still obtains the previous link. If that makes sense.

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman so you want this effect to be applied only on 1 div i.e. box1 and not on box2??

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this:

```
$('a').hover(function (){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", link + '?color=' + somerandomcolor);
}, function (){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('?'));
    $(this).attr("href", link);
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f4dqqzju/2/

Learn more about `hover`: https://api.jquery.com/hover/